# Jewish views on patriotism/nationalism

Tags: hashkafah-philosophy, chutz-laaretz, politics-government

I heard a lecture in which a rabbi espoused very negative views against nationalism in a July 4th speech.  What are Jewish sources that counter his claim, that is, sources in which the Rabbis/great Jews see a need or benefit, etc. for these ideas? I am referring to lawful countries that are good to the Jews like the USA.

Comment: The Rabbi of the Shul I attend is extremely patriotic.

Comment: The Lubavitcher Rebbe called America a "medinah shel chesed" (quoted [here](http://m.chabad.org/m/article_cdo/aid/1340589)).

Comment: @ba - You can use that as a source to answer this question.

Comment: not going to flesh this out into an answer, but in many shuls (nearly all I've been to), we pray for the local country on Shabbas (and sometimes its soldiers). Also many shuls hang an American flag on all days of the year.

Comment: It was an Englishman who defined patriotism as the last refuge of scoundrels, and an American who called it the first.

Comment: When you say nationalism, do you mean patriotism (pride in one's homeland), or some extreme form of nationalism?

Comment: http://shesileizeisim.blogspot.com/2013/07/the-mitzva-of-patriotism.html

Comment: I think there may be a misunderstanding between the exact issue that @SethJ brought. Is it patriotism (which I don't know of sources for), nationalism for a country (") or nationalism for Judaism[seeing Judaism as a nationality] (which many hold is totally wrong)

Answer (score 5):

I remember learning once that Rabbi Avigdor Miller used to hang up an American flag every year on the 4th of July and believed that all Jews should do the same. Although I could be gravely mistaken, it seems to me that this practice should be considered very pro-patriotism.

(Unfortunately I don't have a direct citation from a written source handy, but I will try to find one at some point if I ever get around to it. Alternatively, if you do a [Google search](http://www.google.com/) for [rabbi miller july 4 flag](http://bit.ly/MA19Wt), you can find the same thing.)

Comment: havai mispallel bishlomo shel malchus. Its in perek.

Comment: Pirkei Avos, chapter