# July 4th celebrations in Halacha

Tags: halacha, chutz-laaretz, non-jewish-holidays

Halachic issues around a secular holiday have been discussed here in relation to [Thanksgiving](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/4120/thanksgiving-meal-allowed), but what about July 4th (Independence Day in the United States)?

Are there any issues with performing any of the recognized [celebrations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Independence_Day_(United_States)#Customs):

- Making a picnic or BBQ for the purposes of marking that day
- Attending a parade in honor of July 4th
- Watching or igniting (in states where the latter is legal) fireworks

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/17283/jewish-views-on-patriotism-nationalism

Comment: The Journal of Halacha article that discussed Thanksgiving also discussed July 4th ....I'll see if I can track it down

Comment: Should this be tagged [tag:current-events] ? :P

Comment: Perhaps it matters if you are in the US or not.

Comment: July 4th passed. I beg anyone that answers, don't take away my 4th of July hot dogs ;-) Seriously, how would the questions you raise be any different from how Israelis celebrate Yom Ha'atzma'ut? (Except that you don't celebrate that holiday on July 4)

Comment: @DanF Because July 4th has much less to do with Judaism.

Comment: Lighting fireworks should be OK providing that you do so safely. Unless you're professional, I think it's better to watch. Barbeques - OK, as long as you invite others, (remember to include me next year :-) and make shish kebabs and / or corn. Parades? Can't say - I've never seen any for July 4. It is OK to swim and sing "Happy Birthday, America" in the pool.