# The Belzer Rebbe's approach to nationalism and zionism

Tags: sources-mekorot, am-yisrael-jewish-nation, zionism, belz

In "The Rabbis Speak Out", the 3rd Belzer Rebbe, Rabbi Yissachar Dov Rokeach is quoted (Kuntres 22 Cheshvan, p. 108) in saying that:

> Zionism itself is founded on denial of G-d‟s providence, reward and punishment and the coming of the redeemer. Nationalism is built only on the ruins of the holy Torah, belief in G-d, His prophets, and the Talmudic Sages. Therefore, even if the movement were led by G-d-fearing, righteous men with the best of intentions, it would be impossible for it not to destroy faith and Torah.

The simple meaning behind nationalism, according to the [Merriam -Webster dictionary](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/nationalism), is "loyalty and devotion to a nation". So, why would "nationalism is being built only on the ruins of the Holy Torah, believe in G-d [...]"?

1. **Are there any seforim that discuss why (zionistic) nationalism is not a Torah-idea?**
2. <s>And where can this kuntres (קונטרס כ״ב מר חשון) be found?</s>

Edit: I searched in [here](https://www.truetorahjews.org/images/belz.pdf)
but also not available there.

Comment: Related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/17283/27180

Comment: Comments have been deleted herefrom. Please review [the purpose of comments](/help/privileges/comment) before adding more.

Comment: Not the Belzer Rebbe's shittah per se, but R' Elchonon Wasserman wrote the [ikvesa d'meshicha](https://daat.ac.il/daat/ezrachut/tsiyonut/ikveta.pdf) with a section called "Hara'ayon Haleumi" (page 47) about nationalism and its antithesis to Torah hashkafah.

Answer (score 1):

B"H found it!

It is in the Kuntres 22 Mar Cheshvan, available on Otzar HaChochmah for instance. It reads [(p. 109)](https://tablet.otzar.org/#/book/197187/p/114/t/0.249995551927648881234/fs/5NDHOtkhSJfKsIhf8YAzCrr6xC2LzHjp9qX4JEF9raPu/start/0/end/45/c):

> הציונות בעצמה מיוסדת על ההכחשה בהשגחת ה' ית' בעקרי שכר ועונש ובביאת הגואל והלאומיות הדוברת בה אינה אלא התמלאות מחרבנה של הדת הקדושה ובאמונה בה' ובנביאיו ובחכמי התורה שבע"פ הקדושים ולפיכך גם אילו יצוייר שתתנהג על ידי יראים ותיקים בכוונה טובה אי אפשר לה שלא תהרוס את האמונה והדת

That deals with the second question: "where can this kuntres be found". I am still looking for an answer to question 1 though.

Comment: As suggested in the vanished comments, this quote doesn't speak about nationalism in general, but about nationalism rooted in Zionist ideals.

Comment: I think there is room to quibble with the translation in the OP.

Comment: @deuteronomy? Please feel free to provide a better translation :)

Comment: The phrase והלאומיות הדוברת בה here sounds like he is condemning nationalism that stems from Zionism, which he defines as founded upon a denial of Torah fundamentals. It does not sound like a writ large condemnation of "nationalism" per se, but rather a particular species of nationalism.

Comment: @Deuteronomy thanks, the question still remains why :)

Answer (score 0):

See here:
https://www.nkusa.org/Historical_Documents/TheRabbisSpeakOut.htm

It's really just a compendium of quotes from famous Rabbis, with references to specific books which were the original source.

Comment: Welcome to Mi Yodeya. My quote is located there, so I don’t see how this answers the question. But thanks for your effort!

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/50811)